# How can I force clang to throw errors when the code doesn't strictly conform to the standard?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm writing a C++11 library and I want it to work with every compiler that supports C++11. I don't want to accidentally write code that isn't standard (e.g. uses language extensions like VLAs or blocks). How can I force clang to disable all language extensions so that I can only write conformant code?

Comment: I don't think you can. You can make all diagnostics that the standard requires into a hard error (`-pedantic-errors` with GCC, I think also adopted by clang), but without language extensions, some of the standard headers cannot be implemented, so if you completely disable all extensions, you can no longer use those headers...

Comment: clang does not emit warnings inside system headers (not even ones which are promoted to errors with `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror`), so there's no problem with standard headers if you enable `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [one of these](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cl_diagnostics):

```
-pedantic: Warn on language extensions.

-pedantic-errors: Error on language extensions.
```